# Подскажите аналоги класса DataTable в с# для java. Нужен класс для создания и работы с таблицами

Tags: java, c#, библиотеки, table, таблицы

Нужно хранить данные в таблице в java коде, без использования баз данных. ResultSet не подходит и jTable тоже. Нужно, чтобы по функционалу примерно была как DataTable в C#.

Comment: Что значит _"хранить данные в таблице в java коде"_?  Для хранения данных в табличном виде есть масса форматов: как текстовые CSV/TSV, XML (или даже JSON), так и бинарные - parquet, MS Excel, сериализованные коллекции (списки) Java-объектов, персистентные коллекции и т.д..  Также аналогом C# `DataTable` условно можно считать не свинговый UI-компонент `JTable`, а скорее интерфейс [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), правда его имплементация `DefaultTableModel` использует устаревшие `Vector`'а или даже массивы сырых объектов.